# Calculate Max-Min value and corresponding parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have two functions `funA` and `funB` which are also functions `a,b,x`,and `y` where `a,b>= 0` and `1=<x=<2` and `0=<y=<1`. Lets say a and b are fixed, and I want to find `max{min(funA,funB)}`in `1=<x<=2` and `0=<y=<1`.

I found it by creating a table by using different step sizes for `x` and `y`.

However, I still need to find that corresponding `x` and `y` values. Can someone please help me to find those vales?

Further, I found that my method really slow and take longer time. Do you have any smarter idea to get `max{min(funA,funB)}` value and corresponding `x` and `y`?

```
funA[a_, b_, x_, y_] := y/2 Log[1 + 2 a - (2 a)/x];
funB[a_, b_, x_, y_] := y/2 Log[1 + (2 a b)/y - a b x];
maxAB[a_, b_, sx_, sy_] := 
  Max[Table[
    Table[Min[{funA[a, b, x, y], funB[a, b, x, y]}], {x, 1.0001, 
      1.9999, sx}], {y, 0.0001, 0.9999, sy}]];
```

Example:

```
In[14]:= maxAB[1.3, 0.7, 0.001, 0.002]    
Out[14]= 0.254961
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `NMaximize`?

```
NMaximize[{
 Min[{funA[1.3, 0.7, x, y], funB[1.3, 0.7, x, y]}], 1 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 1},
{{x, 1, 2}, {y, 0, 1}}]
```

> `{0.254965, {x -> 1.55733, y -> 0.775248}}`

To grab the max, x, and y values to later export, you can try:

```
Clear[x, y];
a = Range[1.3, 2, 0.1];
b = Range[0.7, 1.4, 0.1];
With[{m = 
 NMaximize[{Min[{funA[#[[1]], #[[2]], x, y], funB[#[[1]], #[[2]], x, y]}], 
   1 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y}]},
  {m[[1]], x /. m[[2]], y /. m[[2]]}
 ] & /@ Thread[{a, b}]
```

Comment: @ kale Thanks a lot !!! Can you please let me know how can I extract max value, `x` and `y` separately? Because I want to `Export` those values to excel file for different `a` and `b` values.

Comment: `{max, {x1, y1}} = {#[[1]], {x, y} /. #[[2]]} &@%` should capture those values.

Comment: Can you please add this to above code? I am not that good with mathematica to handle.

Comment: One can use `NMaxValue[]` and `NArgMax[]` separately if needed.

Comment: @Frey See update. Also, it's best to not accept the answer right away, because an awful lot of smart folks hang around here who can probably come up with more unique or efficient way to solve your problem.

Comment: @kale Thats cooolll. You save my day :) Thanks again !!!